# How to remove particle Patches from specific spots on the object?

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, particles

So I want to create an animation with a teddybear that moves his head and hands. I got all the moves done together with scenes and so on. The only Problem is that in the render the eyes and nose of the bear aren't visible. I tried to part the eyes and nose from the body, but then I need to move them independely for every scene. I also tried the cut tool in the particle mode together with the delete of particles, which ended somehow wrong. Then there was also the parent thingy to make the eyes follow the rest of the body. I think I did this one wrong? But I'm not sure, because somehow the head came off the body? This is my first time ever creating this sort of thing, so have patience with me. Thank you in advance for the answers.
[image]